# getting the metal king armor

Tags: dragon-quest-series, dragon-quest-v

So you get the Metal King Armor from Metal Dragon's. According to [Bestiary Guide 3.0](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/942423-dragon-quest-v-hand-of-the-heavenly-bride/faqs/55921) Metal Dragon's have a drop rate of 1/256. My question is...  does is matter in which order the Metal Dragon dies?

According to [Monster Recruitment Guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/942423-dragon-quest-v-hand-of-the-heavenly-bride/faqs/59379) in order to recruit a monster the monster you're trying to recruit needs to be the last recruitable monster killed. So if another recruitable monster dies after the one you're trying to get dies then you're guaranteed not to be able to get your desired monster. Do item drops behave similarly? ie. if you kill a monster that drops items after killing another one that drops items are you pretty much guaranteed not to get a drop from your desired monster?

For all I know it could be the exact opposite. You only get the item drop if the monster is the first one killed.

Related to this if you were in a battle with 3x Metal Dragon's would your odds of getting an item drop be 1/256 still or would it be 3/256?